# Unnecessary scrollbars appear in Chrome and IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm tearing my hair out for a couple of days on a "simple" css case with two nested `div`.

Basically, I have two `div`; a **container** and a **content**. To reproduce the case, I've attached a *jsfiddle* link below. The width and the height in pixels of the content are deduced from the container size and you need to input these values by hand by using chrome developer tool for instance. At the end, if you take a look to the size of the content via a developer tool, the container and the content have the same size in pixel. Under Chrome and IE, scrollbars appears whereas the two `div` have the same size but with FF they don't. 
Of course, I could get rid of the `overflow: auto` but I'd rather like to understand what's wrong and what could be solved my issue.

See an example below.

Link to the example: [Scrollbars issue with Chrome&IE](http://jsfiddle.net/azeq/M8tPF/6/)

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The scrollbars are jsFiddle's iframe scrollbars, aren't they...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are, also note that you have a space between the `-moz-` and `box-sizing` in `-moz- box-sizing: border-box;` that might cause some inconsistencies as well

Comment: Scrollbars belong to the div container I think (removing `overflow: auto` make them disappear).

Comment: in IE scroll bars will be visible unless you use `overflow:hidden`. Thats the default property of IE. I think you cannot do anything with that

Comment: I tested the example in Chrome and IE and it displayed without scroll bars in both...

Answer (score -3):

You should use `overflow:hidden` to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: Or `overflow: auto` to hide when not neccessary only. You shall add that.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to hide both scroll you should use **overflow:hidden** .

Comment: Yes, I know but my question is: "Why is it happened? It doesn't make sense to me..."